# How can I update a unique string in a shell-script with the output of a seperate function?

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, string, output, expect

Due to my laziness, I have written an extremely "messy" series of scripts in order to auto-initiate my openvpn. The configuration file I am using comes vpnbook.com/freevpn.

To get the password I use:

```
lynx --dump --nolist vpnbook.com/freevpn | grep -i password | sort -u | cut -b 18,19,20,21,22,23,24
```

The password is returned from the website.

Then, I use an expect script to automatically login (the user name is always vpnbook, but the password changes depending on the week):

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn openvpn /vpn/vpnbook-ca1-tcp80.ovpn ### my vpn configuration file ###
expect "*?sername:*"
send -- "vpnbook\r"
expect "*?assword:*"
### This next line sends the password that changes by the week, which I...
###...unfortunately need to update manually (for lack of a better method):
send -- "weekly-password\r"
```

The problems I am running into when attempting to automatically update the password:

1) I can't call lynx directly from the expect environment.

2) Since the password changes, I am not certain how to replace the
the unique pass-phrase from the previous week with the updated version in :

```
send -- "unique-previous-password\r"
```

3) I am not certain how use the string output from the lynx function as an input variable for editing the password from the previous week (located in my expect script).

Quite clearly, I am not "the brightest" programmer (nor am I the most efficient). However, at the end of the day, my only goal is to fully initialize my vpn by typing a single command (as I mentioned before, I am lazy).

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `expect`/`tcl` script, you can use:

```
send "$env(PASSWORD)\r"
```

And call your `expect` script with with:

```
PASSWORD=$(elinks -dump...) /path/to/your/expect/script
```

Note that you can use `cut -b18-24` for short.

Comment: Thank you for your time -- This was a fantastic (not to mention simple) solution to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Stéphane's solution is very elegant, but in case you don't want to download and parse the password every time, you can retain your two step process with something like this:

Modify your password retrieval command to this:

```
sed -e '$ d' -i .bak f && echo -n "send -- \"" >> f && lynx --dump --nolist vpnbook.com/freevpn | grep -i password | sort -u | cut -b 18-24 >> f && echo "\\r\"" >> f
```

For brevity, I've called your expect script file `f`. In reality it needs to be the complete `/path/to/your/expect/script` unless you're already in the same directory as the script.

Then call your expect script as usual.

Broken down, the extended command works like this:

- `sed -e '$ d' -i .bak f` Find the last line (`$`) in `f` and delete it (`d`). Careful of the `-e` and `-i` switches - they are different/not supported on some platforms. `-e` explicitly specifies the command when the `-i` switch is in use, and `-i` means to modify the file in-place, saving a backup with the `.bak` extension.
- `&&` execute the next command if the previous one succeeds.
- `echo -n "send -- \"" >> f` Append to the file (`>> f`) without a newline (`-n`) the first part of the send expect function.
- `lynx...` Your original command, except the result is appended to the file (`>> f`).
- `echo "\\r\"" >> f` Append the last part of the send expect function.

Comment: I would enthusiastically "up-vote" your answer [ if only I had more than 15 reputation]. The thought processes / techniques presented your solution are extremely useful (not to mention, highly applicable to a variety of "slightly different" problems), and I am grateful for the opportunity to add them to my "repertoire." Thank you very much for your time and expertise.